# Search for custom properties in TIFF files with Windows Search

Tags: windows, tiff, ifilter, windows-search

I would like to extend the Windows Search. It should be able to search for some custom properties in TIFF files.

Is it generally possible to extend the default implementation of the corresponding `IPropertyStore` or `IFilter`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Comment: It's all about adding support for new file format, but nothing about extending existing formats. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you were about to implement a whole *new* TIFF filter, sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Reusing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678443%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Looks like delegation is COM's way of extending.